# Action of Spin Operator on Dirac Spinor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

This is my first post, although I often use physics stack exchange. Thanks.
I am solving P. Ramond’s text on QFT.
I am stuck with the action of the spin operator on the Dirac spinor. What confuses me is that the problem asks to do it in a representation independent way. I tried the definition
\begin{equation}
(S_{\rho \sigma})_{\mu}^{\nu}=\iota (g_{\rho\mu}\delta_{\sigma}^{\nu} - g_{\sigma\mu}\delta_{\rho}^{\nu})
\end{equation}
together with the anti-commutator of gamma matrices.

Reference: P. Ramond Field theory: A modern primer 2nd Edn section 1.4 problem B.